# Knowledge Graph vs Ontology vs RDF Graph

Tags: rdf, ontology, knowledge-graph

I made a small RDF graph that looks as follows:

```
@prefix ex: http://example.org/ . 
@prefix rdfs: http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema# .

ex:a a ex:C, ex:S .

ex:C rdfs:subClassOf ex:D .

ex:D rdfs:subClassOf ex:E .
```

Now I am confused if I could call my RDF graph a knowledge graph as well or an Ontology. I tried to read various sources and those did not help me clear up my confusion.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between knowledge graphs and ontologies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72848400/difference-between-knowledge-graphs-and-ontologies)

Comment: @Bergi I've seen the post before, but I still wanted to double check if the RDF graph that I made can qualify as a knowledge graph.

Comment: Sure, why do you think it wouldn't qualify? Although there's not much knowledge in your example, the entities don't even have labels.

Comment: I deliberately did not add labels because I am trying to analyse a reasoning algorithm that I made by myself, which carries out the reasoning process based on the given graph. Now that I am writing my report about my reasoning algorithm, I was confused if my RDF graph can even be called a knowledge graph. Hence, I posted the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current scientific definition of the term 'Knowledge Graph' is from the Hogan et al. [paper](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/3447772) and says:

> [...] a graph of data intended to accumulate and convey knowledge of the real world, whose nodes represent entities of interest and whose edges represent potentially different relations between these entities.

This is a quite inclusive definition and includes RDF Graphs. The linked paper talks about that in Section 2.

Your example is therefore a RDF Graph and a Knowledge Graph.

Regarding the term 'Ontology', the two subClassOf statements

> ex:C rdfs:subClassOf ex:D .

> ex:D rdfs:subClassOf ex:E .

would be part of an ontology (T-Box) that describe a *schema* for data.

The statements

> ex:a a ex:C, ex:S .

would be instance data (A-box) using the ontology to describe the individual 'ex:a'.

It is fine to include both the ontology and instance data in one graph. However, I would be hesitant to call the short example you posted a fleshed out ontology as there are for example no properties and no metadata about the ontology.

Answer (score 0):

Also recall that both are domain and application/use specific simplifications of the real world.

The trivial knowledge graph example given is a protype, not an actual knowledge graph, just as without actual concepts it isn't an actual ontology.

See the WP page on *Necessary and Sufficient*.